# Neoid polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, polymorphic-associations, graph-databases

I am a little confused about how `Neoid` implements relationships compared to `neo4j` gem itself.

In Neo4j we specify relationships (a.k.a edges) inside node declaration through `has_n` and `has_one` directives:

```
class Person
   include Neo4j::NodeMixin
   property :name, index: :exact
   property :city

   has_n :friends
   has_one :address
end
```

There is no explicit declaration on what class the other end of these relationships belong to, as long as it is a `node`.
But `Neoid` is a different story. You have to specify the relationship in an `ActiveRecord` model which is usually the join table/model, as in the example from `Neoid` homepage:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Neoid::Node

  has_many :likes
  has_many :movies, through: :likes

  neoidable do |c|
    c.field :slug
    c.field :display_name
  end
end
```

Movie:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Neoid::Node

  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes

  neoidable do |c|
    c.field :slug
    c.field :name
  end
end
```

Like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

  include Neoid::Relationship

  neoidable do |c|
    c.relationship start_node: :user, end_node: :movie, type: :likes
  end
end
```

As you can see, in order to specify a relationship between `Movie` and `User`, a join model (`Like`) has intervened (which maps to an edge in our graph database). Unlike embedded `neo4j` API, there are explicit declarations on classes of an edge endpoints (`:user` and `:movie` in this example).

That being said, I can present my case: I have my SQL database setup, I want to add some kind of suggestion/compatibility feature to the program. `Neoid` seems promising given current situation of my application. But I've one doubt I was hoping you could shed some light on. 
Is it possible to adapt abstract nature of an edge endpoints in `Neiod` using active record polymorphism option? Such as in :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Neoid::Node

  has_many :likes, 
  has_many :books, through: :likes
  has_many :movies, through: :likes
  has_many :sports, through: :likes

  neoidable do |c|
    c.field :name
  end
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Neoid::Node

  has_many :likes, as: :likable
  has_many :users, through: :likes

  neoidable do |c|
    c.field :title
    c.field :author
  end
end
#same setup for movies and sports

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :likable, polymorphic: true

  include Neoid::Relationship

  neoidable do |c|
    c.relationship start_node: :user, end_node: :likable, type: :likes
  end
end
```

Will this code work, or I'm getting it wrong? Do I need to change my approach?
I want to make sure before messing around in my code. Any insights will be appreciated...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm wondering about this too.

Comment: @Chris, after posting the question, I began experimenting on this. It turned out that polymorphic option is a no-go and raised all kinds of errors! I ended up developing my own module to handle this through neography gem. I couldn't craft a clean API, so I didn't share my module, but I can post it as a gist if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your code. I've gone down the neo4j gem, which integrates nicely with activeRecord and no longer requires jruby.

Comment: @Chris, sorry for the delay. Here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/Ferixz/26e78208ebc9e0adbf97). I wrote it for a demo-app (showcasing Graph Databases and it's applications). I didn't expect highly of it, but I'd appreciate your comments.